# NDVI chart of sampled points

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, ndvi, chart

I'm working with Sentinel 2 satellite and I have sampled on the map **4 blue points indicating an irrigated areas**, and other **4 red points for non-irrigated ones**.

Then, I have considered 4 collections, one for each month, starting by May

```py
#May
collection_mag = (ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
              .filter(ee.Filter.lt("CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE", 10)) 
              .filterDate('2019-05-01', '2016-05-31')
              .filterBounds(area))

#June
collection_giu = (ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
              .filter(ee.Filter.lt("CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE", 10)) 
              .filterDate('2019-06-01', '2019-06-30')
              .filterBounds(area))

#July              
collection_lul = (ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
              .filter(ee.Filter.lt("CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE", 10)) 
              .filterDate('2019-07-01', '2019-07-31')
              .filterBounds(area))

#August
collection_ago = (ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
              .filter(ee.Filter.lt("CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE", 10)) 
              .filterDate('2019-08-01', '2019-08-31')
              .filterBounds(area))
```

For each collection, I have calculated the NDVI, then reduced the collection into one image

```py
def NDVI(image):
    return image.expression('float(b("B8") - b("B4")) / (b("B8") + b("B4"))')

img_mag = collection_mag.map(NDVI).mean()
img_giu = collection_giu.map(NDVI).mean()
img_lul = collection_lul.map(NDVI).mean()
img_ago = collection_ago.map(NDVI).mean()
```

This is the result by now (printing only the last month collection) - : 
[image: This is the result by now]

I want to plot a chart indicating the NDVI value, month by month, of the sampled points. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Although I did this within the Javascript code editor, code should be fairly similar for the Python environment:

first, make some geometry you should have. I would recommend making a feature of each point and turn it into a feature collection.

```
// import a geometry with 8 points
```

get the image collection you like:

```
// import image collection             
var collection = (ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
              .filter(ee.Filter.lt("CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE", 40)) // if you set this to low, you won't have images sometimes
              .filterBounds(geometry));
```

Then make a monthly composite image using e.g. this function:

```
// make monthly NDVI composites
var listMonths = ee.List.sequence(1,12);
var monthlyNDVI = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(listMonths.map(function(month){
  var start = ee.Date.fromYMD(2019, month, 1);
  var end = ee.Date.fromYMD(2019, month, 1).advance(1, 'month');
  var images = collection.filterDate(start, end);
  var NDVI =  images.map(function(image){
    return image.expression('float(b("B8") - b("B4")) / (b("B8") + b("B4"))').rename('NDVI');
  });
  return NDVI.mean().set('system:time_start', start);
}));
```

And print a chart using:

```
// print chart and collection
print(monthlyNDVI);
var chart = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion(monthlyNDVI, geometry, ee.Reducer.mean(), 'NDVI', 10);
print(chart)
```

[Link code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/5e6939648f63cef77326fc171549555d)

Comment: Thank you so much for the response, I will try to traduce this in Pyhton!